# MSB3422 Failed to retrieve VC project information through the VC project engine object model. MSB3425

Tags: msbuild

I'm getting the following errors from MSBuild while trying to build a solution:

```
C:\dev\MySln.sln : warning MSB3422: Failed to retrieve VC project information through the VC project engine object model. Unable to determine default tool for the specified file configuration.
C:\dev\MySln.sln : warning MSB3425: Could not resolve VC project reference "C:\dev\MyProj.vcproj".
```

Have you got any ideas on what's causing this and how it can be resolved? I've seen other postings about similar, but different errors such as when the MSB3422 error has a different message and shows "Illegal characters in path.", but I haven't seen any useful information about how to solve the error I'm getting where it says "Unable to determine default tool for the specified file configuration.".

Thanks.

---

I found this, but it doesn't really help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/b470f111-9321-4b43-8bd1-7fcf67c2d402

Comment: You are likely missing some component. What type of project is MyProj? I think I am getting this or a similar error when I load a database or SSIS project and the SQL Server components are not installed.

Comment: I can build the solution fine in the IDE.

Comment: Are you maybe calling msbuild from the wrong framework version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague fixed this issue by reregistering the VC project engine dll:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\VCProjectEngine.dll

Comment: But, it doesn't seem to work for me. I thought I had it solved, but now it's come back again on a different build script.

Comment: FYI (I had to look this up) - How to register (or re-register) a DLL or OCX file
Go to the Run item on the Start menu and type:
`regsvr32 <path & filename of dll or ocx>`